# Best way to force download file with php?

Tags: php, xml, kml, domdocument

I have read many things about force downloading with php, but none of them really answer my question.

My PHP code reads an XML file located in the same directory as the PHP file as a new DOMDocument. It then changes the XML file based on user input. Then I want it to force download the changed XML file as a KML file. How do I do that? This is the closest I've gotten:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument;
$xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$file = 'master.xml';
$file = realpath($file);
$xml->Load($file);

header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=output.kml');
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml');
$xml->save('output.kml');
readfile('output.kml');
```

But nothing happens. No file is saved anywhere, and no file is downloaded.

Comment: Basically, a user will input some values and hit submit. My code will create a KML file for them, then the KML file will automatically start downloading. I know there are ways to make that happen. But if it's easier, then it can ask them if they want to download the file. Whatever way is better to get them that file.

Answer (score 1):

Consider segmenting the XML file creation and file download and use [file_put_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) with [saveXML()](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php) to save DOMDocument as an external file.

```
...    
file_put_contents('output.kml', $xml->saveXML());    
$local_file = 'output.kml';
$download_file = 'download.kml';

if (file_exists($local_file)) {

    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml');    
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename='.$download_file);
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize($local_file));
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($local_file);
    exit;

}
```

Comment: Still not doing anything. I think it's the saving part that isn't working. I can't make it save no matter what I do.

Comment: What type of object is `$xml`? If `$xml` is a DOMDocument object, then `file_put_contents()` should save content to file. Check your home directory (not where php script resides). Also, please post more of code to show how `$xml` is created?

Comment: There's nothing in the home directory or any other directory. I have edited my post to show how I created `$xml`.

Comment: Code looks correct. What does your error log say? Do you see a `master.xml` file and is it non-empty?

Comment: The `master.xml` is the file I'm reading from and manipulating, trying to create a new KML file from. It is definitely not empty. And I don't see any error logs. I'm sorry, I'm really new to all of this, so I just don't know what to do here haha.